# How can I make a library find Eigen with CMake in macOS?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cmake, include, macos-sierra

I am trying to compile my project with CMake which includes the Ceres Solver library. I'm using macOS Sierra with Xcode 8.1 dev tools.

I installed the library with Homebrew (brew install ceres-solver). I downloaded and tested the binary manually (http://ceres-solver.org/building.html#mac-os-x), and that works just fine. But I can't include it in my own project because it can't seem to find Eigen. Here is a complete example:

ceres-test/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)                                                                                            
project(CeresTest)                                                                                                             
find_package(ceres REQUIRED)                                                                                                   
add_executable(                                                                                                                
  TestCeres                                                                                                                    
  src/test_ceres.cpp                                                                                                           
)                                                                                                                              
target_link_libraries(                                                                                                         
  TestCeres                                                                                                                    
  ceres                                                                                                                        
)
```

ceres-test/src/test_ceres.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "ceres/ceres.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << "Works." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

How I compile it:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Full output:

```
me: ceres-test $ mkdir build
me: ceres-test $ cd build/
```

cmake

```
me: build $ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000042
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000042
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found required Ceres dependency: Eigen version 3.2.10 in /usr/local/include/eigen3
-- Found required Ceres dependency: Glog in /usr/local/include
-- Found Ceres version: 1.11.0 installed in: /usr/local
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/me/Tests/ceres-test/build
```

make

```
me: build $ make
Scanning dependencies of target TestCeres
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestCeres.dir/src/test_ceres.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/me/Tests/ceres-test/src/test_ceres.cpp:3:
In file included from /usr/local/include/ceres/ceres.h:37:
In file included from /usr/local/include/ceres/autodiff_cost_function.h:132:
In file included from /usr/local/include/ceres/internal/autodiff.h:145:
/usr/local/include/ceres/jet.h:165:10: fatal error: 'Eigen/Core' file not found
#include "Eigen/Core"
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/TestCeres.dir/src/test_ceres.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/TestCeres.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have no idea how to resolve this. None of the solutions I found online helped. CMake seems to be finding the Eigen library just fine, so I'm not sure how to add it in.

On a side note I cannot include "Eigen/Core" directly either, but the tests that I was able to compile do include it and those are fine. I'm not familiar how to deal with these kinds of problems with CMake.

**Edit:** I can get it to compile if I include it as "eigen3/Eigen/Core" but I can't change the source code for Ceres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed with

```
include_directories(${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

in the CMakeLists....

Comment: I appreciate that you took the time to answer your own question after finding the solution. This fixed it for me as well and probably saved me quite some time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For my mac mini m1.
I found the eigen library through
`brew link --overwrite eigen`.
It's located on
`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/eigen/3.4.0_1/include/eigen3`